# How to handle form control for PostgreSQL’s point type in IHP?

Tags: ihp

IHP's PostgreSQL implementation supports the POINT column type, and the IHP API has functions to parse and serialize, but I how to create form fields in a New and Edit View for it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `textField` for that:

```hs
{(textField #location)}
```

But IHP currently has no support on how to turn the Point data type into a text format for the text field. You can manually add this by placing this type instance in your `Application.Helper.View` module:

```hs
module Application.Helper.View where

import IHP.ViewPrelude

-- Here you can add functions which are available in all your views


instance InputValue Point where
    inputValue point = inputValue (get #x point) <> "," <> inputValue (get #y point)
```

Then a point will render like this inside the text field:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This exact format seems like a good idea since it can be copied and pasted from Google Maps. Might be helpful to add info on how to access x and y, like here (assuming you've got Places with a location column):

`renderGoogleMapsUrl = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=" <> show (x xy) <> "," <> show (y xy)`
`where`
`Just xy = get #location place`

But then, I should maybe extend the question too.